# Adding text to plots in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using groupby to extract portions of a dataframe (stackprofile) for plotting, followed by a for loop for making the plots.  This works.

I now need to add text to each of the plots from a different dataframe (wshdarea).

Code updated with example data included:

```
wshdarea = [[1,1840,745],[2,18548,7506],[3,19109,7733]]
wshdf = pandas.DataFrame(wshddata, columns=['ID','Acres','Hectares'])

stackprofile = pandas.DataFrame([[0,1180,1],
                           [5,1181,1],
                           [10,1182,1],
                           [0,1173,2],
                           [5,1174,2],
                           [10,1173,2],
                           [0,1166,3],
                           [5,1166,3],
                           [10,1165,3]], columns=['FIRST_DIST','FIRST_Z','LINE_ID'])

ymin = stackprofile['FIRST_Z'].min()
ymax = stackprofile['FIRST_Z'].max()
    
groupby = stackprofile.groupby('LINE_ID')    
lines = list(stackprofile['LINE_ID'].unique())

for i in lines:    
    
    line1 = groupby.get_group(i)
    x = line1['FIRST_DIST']
    y = line1['FIRST_Z']
    #ymin = line1['FIRST_Z'].min()
    #ymax = line1['FIRST_Z'].max()
    plt.figure(figsize=(18,14))
    plt.scatter(x, y, c = "blue", s= 10)
    plt.plot(x,y, c = "green")
    plt.ylim((ymin - .5), ymax)
    plt.xlabel('FIRST_Z')
    plt.ylabel(i)
    plt.text(5,5, i,
             horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center',
             transform = ax.transAxes,
             fontsize = 16)
    
    
    #for b in wshdarea:
        #plt.scatter(x, y, c = "blue", s= 10)
    
    #plt.text(4,4, int(wshdarea['Acres']),
             #horizontalalignment='center',
             #verticalalignment='center',
             #transform = ax.transAxes,
             #fontsize = 16)
    
    plt.savefig(resultsdir + r"\profile" + str(i) + "test.jpg")
```

I tried making another loop ("for b in wshdarea") inside the original for loop expecting that it would add the text for each record from the wshdarea dataframe, which has the same number of rows as in the lines list, but it fails.

Comment: What does "it fails" mean in this context?

Comment: It plots one graph with no text label and then stops.

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is the error and on what line?

Comment: It runs with no errors as posted above, but not if I uncomment the "for b in wshdarea:" section